# adding a number to the last number in a file

Tags: csv, python-3.x

i made a program where i have data in a csv file i want to use some data from the file in math equations.

the file looks like this

```
 gender,1500,300
```

this is my code

```
 caloriesIn = 1400
 callost = 100
 with open ("fitness file.csv") as csvfile:

    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    for row in readcsv:
        BMR = (row[1])
        caloriesLost = (row[2])
    caloriesLost = caloriesLost + (str(((float(BMR)) - (caloriesIn)) + (int(callost))))

    FitnessFile = open(("fitness file.csv") , "a")
    FitnessInfo = "," + str(caloriesLost)
    FitnessFile.write(FitnessInfo)
    FitnessFile.close()
```

now i want to add the number i just made (caloriesLost) to the last number in the file.
when i run this it just appends 500 (which is what i calculated early as caloriesLost)
to the file like this:

```
 gender,1500,300,500
```

and i need it to add to the last number in the file like this:

```
 gender,1500,800
```

i know it might be a bit confusing and im sorry about that. im still a beginner.
thanks for your help :)

the file is always one line.

Comment: 1) Is there always one line in your csv file? 2) Why four levels of indentation after the "with as"? 3) Why so many useless parentheses? 4) Where is callost defined?

Comment: yes there is always 1 line in my csv file

Comment: callost is equal to 100

Answer (score 0):

If it’s just a single line, then there is no reason to overcomplicate this using the csv module:

```
caloriesIn = 1400
callost = 100
fileName = 'fitness file.csv'

# read data from the file
with open(fileName) as f:
    label, bmr, caloriesLost = f.read().strip().split(',')

# calculate the new caloriesLostvalue    
caloriesLost = float(caloriesLost) + float(BMR) - caloriesIn + callost

# save the new data
with open(fileName, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(','.join((label, bmr, calloriesLost)))
```

Comment: how do i do the same thing but with a file which looks like this:

Comment: test5,16,165.0,male,27.915518824609734,1329.0591,300

Comment: So do you have multiple lines now, or just one line?

Comment: bmr is on row[5] and caloriesLost is on row[6]